# JSF save/restore view state

Tags: jsf, savestate

Here’s the scenario, we have a JSF app using PrimeFaces and running on Tomcat 7, all managed beans are ViewScoped and they have a quite complex structure. Recently we were asked to implement the following requirement: Generate a URL that can be shared among users. By clicking on the link, the view should be restored to the same state saved previously when the link was generated.

In general lines, my idea is to implement a phase listener and invoke saveState/restoreState on viewRoot object accordingly. By the time the URL is generated, the phaseListener will get the UIViewRoot state by invoking saveState and then serialize the object and persist in a database table. The reverse will happen when the link is accessed, the object will be retrieved from the database, deserialized and restored on the UIViewRoot by invoking restoredState.

When trying to restore the state the actual results is not what I expected, since the the managed beans properties are null after invoking restoreState on UIViewRoot.

The saveState is being called after the render phase is completed, and the serializable object looks good as all values are set correctly. The restoreState is being called in the “restore view” phase, I have been trying many combinations about the time the restoreState is invoked (after/before phases) and none seems to work.

For testing purposes I have implemented the methods in a PhaseListener. Here’s the code snippet, the logic to call them is omitted:

```
private void saveState(FacesContext context) {
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = context.getViewRoot();    
    Object savedState = viewRoot.saveState(context);
    if(savedState instanceof Serializable) {
        Serializable s = ((Serializable) savedState);

        try {
            this.serialize(s);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error saving state.", e);
        }
     }
}

private void restoreState(FacesContext context) {
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = new UIViewRoot();
    FileInputStream fis;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("/view.ser");
        Serializable savedState = this.deserialize(fis);

        viewRoot.restoreState(context, savedState);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error restoring state.", e);
    }
}
```

I’m not a JSF expert and therefore I’m not sure if the approach I’m trying to use makes any sense at all, so here’s my question for you JSF gurus: can this requirement be implemented somehow? If yes, what is the correct way to implement it? I have researched the forum and I cannot find something similar that I could reuse.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks ahead.

**UPDATE**:

This is how we managed to save and restore the view state.

The view state is being saved and serialized in the web bean:

```
private void saveViewState(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = context.getViewRoot();
    Object savedState = viewRoot.saveState(context);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    oos.writeObject(savedState);
}
```

In order to restore the state, a phase listener intercepts the Faces Request **before** Restore View phase, deserialize the view state object and invokes `restoreState` on `UIViewRoot`:

```
private void restoreState(FacesContext context) {

    // details omitted
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);

    Serializable viewState = (Serializable) ois.readObject();

    UIViewRoot viewRoot = new UIViewRoot();
    viewRoot.restoreState(context, viewState);
    viewRoot.setRenderKitId(RenderKitFactory.HTML_BASIC_RENDER_KIT);
    viewRoot.setViewId(savedView.getViewId());
    context.setViewRoot(viewRoot);
    context.renderResponse();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The recommended approach to state saving per the JSF Specification is via the `StateManager` component. This is the same component that the JSF runtime uses in its own state-saving operations. While `UIViewRoot#saveState` may give similar results, the `StateManager` and its convenience methods provide guarantees that are mandated by the spec.

- **To save a view state**

  1. Obtain a reference to the `StateManager` associated with your application:

     ```
     FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     StateManager stateManager = ctx.getApplication().getStateManager();
     ```
  2. Use either

     a.   `Object viewState = stateManager.saveView(ctx);`

     b. The `getViewState` convenience method

     ```
     String viewState stateManager.getViewState(ctx);
     ```
- **To restore a view's state**

  ```
  UIViewRoot restoredView = stateManager.writeState(ctx,viewState);
  ```

Comment: Thanks. Using StateManager approach looks good indeed, however we still have problems restoring the view state, probably because the save/restore is not being performed at the correct life cycle phase. We are trying writeState before restore view phase, in this case the renderKitId is null, consequently a NPE is thrown. Invoking writeState after restore view phase causes a NPE when the writeViewStateField(FacesContext facesContext, ResponseWriter responseWriter, Object savedState) is invoked because ResponseWriter is null.

Comment: @TheRodSouza, did you meanwhile figure out where in the life-cycle to call the writeState method? I have the same issue and stuck. Thanks

Comment: @Lev Stefanovich sorry about the delay, it has been long time since I implemented this. Actually the requirement is to save the current view state of the view so that we could share a link of the page with other users. The action is performed by a method in the web bean where you get the view root via context.getViewRoot() and then viewRoot.saveState(context). The saved state object is then returned, serialized and persisted. The restore procedure happens in the RESTORE_VIEW phase. Hope this helps.